# jQuery Chosen - show placeholder at all times

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

Our client wants to show the placeholder (in a multi-select that is using jQuery Chosen) at *all* times - even after one or more selections have been made. Their intent is to make it clear that as many additional choices can be made as desired.

I can modify the text of the placeholder:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#input_1_4").attr("data-placeholder", "Choose one or more");
});
```

But I am not finding a way to modify the behavior so that the placeholder still displays after a choice is made.

The environment is such that we *have* to use Chosen; it is part of a component. We are limited to adding additional JavaScript or CSS to change how things work.

Is there a way to keep the placeholder displaying for the multiselect Chosen field, to encourage additional choices to be made by the user?

**Update**
Here is a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/holmegm/efhLepxs/25/

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#input_1_4").attr("data-placeholder", "Choose one or more");
    jQuery("#input_1_4").chosen();
});
```

```css
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  width: 25em !important;
}
.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices {
  width: 25em !important;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li id="field_1_4"><div class="ginput_container ginput_container_multiselect"><select multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Click to select..." size="7" name="input_4[]" id="input_1_4"  class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="6"><option value="what" >What</option><option value="sure" >Sure</option><option value="this" >This</option><option value="that" >That</option><option value="theOther" >The Other</option></select></div><div class="gfield_description">Please choose one or more types of assistance that you are looking for.</div></li></ul>
```

Note that the placeholder text is present before any choices are made, and then is *not* present after one or more choices has been made. The goal is to have it remain present, not just have empty white space that assumes that users already know how to use this kind of control.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it helps us provide a faster, better answer (i.e. you're not showing us your HTML, etc)

Comment: @ochi, I added a working example to the question.

Comment: Please add it to the question, if the link becomes unreachable for any reason, the question remains incomplete (hence, almost impossible to answer)

Comment: Having said that, I think your approach is against good UI/UX principles.  The reason a placeholder exists is to indicate to the users that an action has not been taken (and provide them with a hint of what values go in a given field).  It's not really meant to give instructions to the users.  Placeholders are supposed to disappear after the action has been taken.  - With this in mind, what don't you just add a label to the input field? (i.e. outside of the `chosen` plugin?

Comment: I respectfully disagree about this violating good UI principles. There is no intrinsic reason for the placeholder to disappear simply because one or more values have been added to the list of those chosen. The UI element for adding more values is still there, waiting for input. In reality this is two elements; a list of values already chosen, and an element for adding new values to the list.

Comment: Difference of opinions, I suppose, but that's not what the placeholder is *intended* for.  It is supposed to be a hint of the expected value for a given field and it is supposed to disappear after an input has been entered. It is not meant to be used for instructions: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#placeholder  - I suppose it is ultimately up to you on how you want to (ab)use it but I would not consider it good UX/UI - I would keep thinking: I already selected an option, why are you still thinking I have not? - Have a good day

Comment: blurfus, answering your question a few years too late, but - since multiple selections are permitted, you *haven't* completed giving your input until you have made *all* of your desired selections. And the code has no way of knowing when that time will be - you could always intend to select one more. Well, unless they have already selected all possible options.

Comment: Again, differences of opinion.  The same can be said about any input field. When you are done entering the field, you have not completed giving the input - you can type or select more or change your mind - Still, that's not what the placeholder text is for.  It is a placeholder so, by definition, temporary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the value of `data-placeholder` attribute (or `default_text` in **chosen** terms) into the `search_field` element after **chosen** is initialized.

Here's one way to do it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#input_1_4").attr("data-placeholder", "Choose one or more");
  jQuery("#input_1_4").on('chosen:ready', function(ev, args) {
    var sender = args.chosen;
    sender.search_field.attr('placeholder', sender.default_text);
  }).chosen();
});
```

```css
  .chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices li.search-field input[type="text"] {
  width: 25em !important;
}

.chosen-container-multi .chosen-choices {
  width: 25em !important;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.7.0/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="field_1_4">
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_multiselect"><select multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Click to select..." size="7" name="input_4[]" id="input_1_4" class="medium gfield_select" tabindex="6"><option value="what" >What</option><option value="sure" >Sure</option><option value="this" >This</option><option value="that" >That</option><option value="theOther" >The Other</option></select></div>
    <div
      class="gfield_description">Please choose one or more types of assistance that you are looking for.</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

});